# Left column elements are "fully-connected" with right column elements in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to implement a specific graph network where all right column elements have to be connected with all left column elements without to be linked itselves.

Suppose a table like this:

```
table=data.frame(matrix(c("A","B","A","C","B","D","1","2","3","1","4","2"),ncol=2))
colnames(table)=c("gene","enhancer")

print(table)

#gene enhancer
#1    A        1
#2    B        2
#3    A        3
#4    C        1
#5    B        4
#6    D        2
```

Here I want a networks like (A--1,C--1), (B--2,D--2), (A--3) and (B--4).

If I use [igraph](/questions/tagged/igraph) package directly, I have networks with indirect edges and I do not want it.
Basically, I want to have subgraph of a bigger graph where all genes are connected with all enhancers.

I have already succeeded to create my wanted networks for one-one linkage, but I cannot create its for more complex relationships.

I tried to use [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) with **group_split** and **group_keys** functions to retrieve connected elements each others. I also used **aggregate** function.
I cannot do it, probably I over-think my problem but it does not seem really trivial.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to exactly what you are tying to get...what do you mean by "indirect edge"? The code you give creates a network like the one that you described. Perhaps you want a bipartite network, since you have two different types of vertices?

Comment: When I talk about "indirect edge" I mean vertices like (A--1,C--1, A--3), the graph can be bipartite without having all my genes connected to all my enhancers. Probably a complete bipartite graph will do the job. My vertices are genes and enhancers in my case.

Comment: So, for example, gene A is connected to each enhancer, gene B is connected to each enhancer, etc?

Comment: Yes if my gene A and gene B are fully-connected to the same set of enhancers so they form a full-bipartite graph, if I'm right.